# Install .apk on device after pushing .apk to device

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to push the .apk onto the device and then install the .apk on the device? I can install the application with the .apk on the host and use "adb install .apk". However I want to do with the .apk on the device and install it from there.

Thanks

Comment: Use a file manager and open it

Comment: `adb install app.apk` is just a shortcut for `adb push app.apk /data/local/tmp/` and then `adb shell pm install /data/local/tmp/app.apk`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I've done it before by putting the .apk somewhere on the device, such as the downloads folder. Then use a file manager (I used Astro) to navigate to the .apk and when you touch the file an option should come up to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of this ways:

- Run your application and using a file explorer, backup your app and save it on your device and just go there and press it to install it.
- Run it wherever you want, virtual device or
  real device (you can cancel run when the prompt appears, just need to compile the apk), next, in your computer, go to the next location:
  yourAppName\app\build\outputs\apk the first one is the correct one!

if you use the second way, you can install it on a virtual device and send it your real device, otherwise you need to install or cancel it after build the apk.

see ya!